# How to convert 48V to 5V in this system?

Tags: batteries, buck

I have built a prototype for monitoring the battery voltage of my off-grid PV system. The prototype is as shown in the clumsy schematic drawing below, and it uses 24 V battery. I use an **[OKI-78SR-5](http://power.murata.com/data/power/oki-78sr.pdf)** to get 5 V for an Arduino board with a GSM shield.

To save the battery, the whole circuit is only switched on once per day (with an external system). So it wakes up just to measure and send the data. This should enable me to run the monitor through the winter. I'm aware that this approach is inaccurate due to eg. temperature change, but I hope to get at least *some* idea of the conditions in a remote location.

The prototype seems to work, **but now I've deviced that my battery system will use 48 V (4 x 12 V) instead of 24 V**. The OKI-78SR-5 only goes up to 36 V.

To convert the system to use 48 V, what should I do?

a) connect another OKI-78SR-5 in series? Is it possible?

b) buy a 48V to 5V converter, eg. http://www2.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Mean-Well/SD-15C-05/ (or would a cheaper one suffice?)

c) only monitor two of the batteries? Pointless, even harmful?

d) just add a resistor? Bad for efficiency!

e) something else?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkCKOF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You could power the OKI78SR from 2 batteries, but still measure the voltage of all 4 (with suitable divider resistors).

Comment: @SteveG An amp draw would make that unwise. But if OP is only doing this for 1 minute a day, that's actually more practical than my solution.

Comment: Larger resistors draw less current. Thus saving power.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest choice would be any number of step-down modules designed for that voltage. 50V input to 5V output can be found for a few bucks (Pun totally intended), with more reliable resellers costing more.

In any case, keep in mind, a GSM shield, from what I could find, plus the arduino, requires 700mA up to 1 amp of power available. Size your regulator accordingly.

And size the input voltage to the max voltage, not just the nominal 48V. If your PV system is charging the batteries at 50+ volts, then your regulator needs to be able to handle that. A car for example, is 12V nominal, normally sees up to 14.5V while charging. In that range, a regulator that can handle up to 72V may be required.

Oh, and your Voltage Divider is incredibly wrong. 100k over 10k, to bring 48V to 5V with under a milliamp draw.

**Update:** If you are only pulling this power one time a day, for x minutes, then maybe you can power it from 2 batteries instead of all four. It's not recommended as a large draw can cause the batteries to discharge unevenly, but if its only a few minutes a day (I'm assuming long enough to gather data and send it via text) then that should be fine.

Comment: Although Arduino advise a 700mA to 1A power supply for the Arduino GSM shield that is very unlikely to be the average current consumption. GSM modems can draw up to 1.5A under exceptional conditions (such as a badly mis-matched antenna) but this is for 1154us every 4615us (ie 1/4 duty cycle). Average current draw is usually around 300mA while it is transmitting.

Comment: @SteveG never played with them. But OP is on a off-grid remote location? Signal, and thus RF power and thus power draw may very well be an issue.

Comment: it doesn't look as if the OP has much data to transmit, his transmit time could be just a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks for all the insights. Maybe I'll find a cheap step-down module.

The resistance of `R1` was a copy-paste error, fixed that now to show my current 24 V setup. Must change that for 48 V setup, of course.

About the required current: yes, at least my GSM shield seems to need a lot more than 1 A, even at an urban location.

Answer (score -2):

For the purpose of monitoring your PV storage increase for a few seconds once a day, the loss is insignificant for a few seconds.

Considering you are adding 2 batteries to make 4 and they will be mismatched, almost any solution you suggested will work including powering from just 24V as @SG indicated.

I think it is still wiser to add capacity in parallel in order to make it insensitive to matching cell capacity or ESR with aging.

Comment: This answer *completely* skips the question's intent of changing power supply requirements.

Comment: the intent may be a poor choice or assumption on my part